# Xcode 14.3.1: Yet another symbols are missing in instruments question

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode14

Leak traces are not symbolicated:

[image]

Profiling debug build:

[image]

And Symbols in Instruments File menu is disabled:

[image]

Any suggestions? Profiling in Xcode 15 beta 4 won't even connect to the process. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Release build configuration to profile your app if you want the Symbols menu item to be enabled. The Symbols menu is used to locate the dSYM file that contains the symbols for your project. If you profile with the Debug build configuration, there is no dSYM file, and that causes the Symbols menu to be disabled.